# How to send web push notification

Tags: angular, laravel, push-notification

I have a Angular PWA running Laravel in the back-end as admin panel. I want to send the web push notification to PWA app when admin creates a News at back end. There is no user registration its a simple website.

I would prefer to got with On signal or FCM push notification.

Any useful site with examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can do this using `laravel` + `redis` + `socket.io` + `socket client`:

```
$ cd your-project
```

**1. Install packages:**

```
$ npm install express ioredis socket.io --save
```

**2. Your package.json file will look like:**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "laravel-elixir": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "ioredis": "^1.4.0",
    "redis": "^0.12.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5"
  }
}

composer require predis/predis
```

**3. Create an Event in Laravel:**

```
php artisan make:event WebPush
```

**4. The entire WebPush.php class should look like:**

```
<?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class WebPush extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> '10'
        );
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

**5. Use this code in Angular:**

```
<script src="js/socket.io.js'"></script>
    <script>
        //var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');
        socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function(message){
            // increase the power everytime we load test route
            $('#power').text(parseInt($('#power').text()) + parseInt(message.data.power));
        });
    </script>
```

**6. Set up three routes like so. Add them to your `app/Http/routes.php` file:**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    // this doesn't do anything other than to
    // tell you to go to /fire
    return "go to /fire";
});

Route::get('fire', function () {
    // this fires the event
    event(new App\Events\EventName());
    return "event fired";
});

Route::get('test', function () {
    // this checks for the event
    return view('test');
});
```

**7. Create the `socket.js` file in your project root:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

**P.S:**

Make sure you have installed `redis` server + connect it to `Laravel` using `.env` or database file.